# Processing chinese character using eyed3 in python

Tags: python, encoding, character-encoding, eyed3

I am using eyed3 to add lyrics, and I had this code for it

```
#-*-coding:utf-8-*-

import eyed3
mp3 = eyed3.load( r'F:\Music\=NEUTRAL=\桜華結界-Perfect Cherry Blossom-\04 - 早乙女の遊戯そして流儀（原曲：東方紅魔郷 U.N.オーエンは彼女なのか？）.mp3'.decode('utf-8'))
mp3.tag.lyrics.set('哈哈测试ひびき')
mp3.tag.save()
```

When I run it with my IDE(pyCharm). It return me a error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "H:/Python/Xiami-music-lyrics/test.py", line 6, in <module>
    mp3.tag.save()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\eyed3\id3\tag.py", line 773, in save
    self._saveV2Tag(version, encoding, max_padding)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\eyed3\id3\tag.py", line 967, in _saveV2Tag
    max_padding)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\eyed3\id3\tag.py", line 881, in _render
    raw_frame = f.render()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\eyed3\id3\frames.py", line 1056, in render
    self.text.encode(id3EncodingToString(self.encoding)))
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe5 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Here is a screenshot on my python console:

[image: screenshot]

How can I fix my code in my IDE in order to let this work? Sorry for the bad english.

Comment: how about change `'哈哈测试ひびき'` to `u'哈哈测试ひびき'`

Comment: Thank you so much. The code is now running smoothly without any error. @WKPlus

Answer (score 4):

```
#-*-coding:utf-8-*-

import eyed3
mp3 = eyed3.load( r'F:\Music\=NEUTRAL=\桜華結界-Perfect Cherry Blossom-\04 - 早乙女の遊戯そして流儀（原曲：東方紅魔郷 U.N.オーエンは彼女なのか？）.mp3'.decode('utf-8'))
mp3.tag.lyrics.set(u'哈哈测试ひびき')
mp3.tag.save(version=eyed3.id3.ID3_DEFAULT_VERSION,encoding='utf-8')
```

solved the problem :-)

Comment: It really made my day